# Meteor send only authorized templates down to the client

Tags: meteor

I know meteor kind of compiles the templates up down to the client. With the meteor-auth system is there a way of only sending down templates when the user has permissions to see them (so they're not visible when inspecting html code on the client end)? For example we don't want to always send down an admin section down to the browser.

For example if I have

```
<template name="admin_main">
    <h2>Admin Menu</h2>
    ....
</template>
```

If my `Meteor.user().profile.userlevel` is `5`, only then I'd like the template to be published to the user. Otherwise the rest of my users can see my admin menu with a bit of js knowledge

Comment: could you place a short example code?

Comment: I don't know if its necessary, but Ive updated my question with a sample, maybe theres a way to add an attribute to `<template>` and find a way in meteor's code to only publish it if the user is logged in with a condition?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that this is possible, yet.

For an Admin section, you could create two separate apps and have them communicate through the same DDP server. This would make sharing code more difficult, however.

> DDP can work with any database, framework, or programming language, and it can work on servers, clients, and mobile devices. **In fact, you can call Meteor.connect to connect to any DDP server -- such as a Meteor app written by someone else! -- and make realtime subscriptions to any data it's publishing.**

http://meteor.com/blog/2012/03/21/introducing-ddp